# extending the element to a list that was used in .pop

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a pseudo-random sequence generator. There are a couple of constraints, the first one being that there should be 24 instances of each sequence and that there should never be a consecutive occurrence of a sequence in the result. This is my code:

```
import random
def rgen():
    block_list =[]
    while len(block_list) != 96:
        sequences = ['seq1','seq2','seq3','seq4']
        block_list.extend(random.sample(sequences, 4))
    for x,y in enumerate(block_list):
        count = 'repeat'
        while count == 'repeat':
            if block_list[x] == block_list[x-1]:
                block_list.pop(x)
                block_list.extend(y)
                count = 'repeat'
            else:
                count = 'no repeat'
    sequence_counts = {'seq1':0,'seq2':0,'seq3':0,'seq4':0}
    for i in block_list:
        for k,v in sequence_counts.items():
            if k == i:
                v += 1
                sequence_counts[k] = v          
    print 'counts for each sequence: ', sequence_counts
    print block_list
```

The end result of this however, is that I end up with something like this at the end of the list:

```
's', 'e', 'q', '1', 's', 'e', 'q', '1', 's', 'e', 'q', '2', 's', 'e', 'q', '4'
```

when I really just want to extend the entire list element not it's characters individually.

so I want to extent the entire strings above which are really:

```
'seq1','seq1','seq2','seq4'
```

Comment: what do you mean by "extend the entire list element not it's characters individually"?

Comment: @SirParselot I would extend 'seq1' not 's' and 'e' and 'q' and '1'

Comment: Do you mean for it to be circular? In the first iteration of the first for loop you are comparing index 0 and index -1?

Comment: @SirParselot not really, that was just a consequence of that being the only way I could think of comparing consecutive list items

Comment: I believe you meant *psuedo*-random, not sudo-random ;)

Comment: @WayneWerner haha, yes you are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem comes from using `extend()` instead of `append()`. [`extend()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) assumes you are adding a list to another list and adds each element of `y` to `block_list`. Your use of `count` is unnecessary since you immediately leave your while loop in the else statement so you can replace it with a `break()`. There is also an issue with the number of each element. The way you have it you are removing an element which changes the value at index `x`. To fix this, you know that the value you pop matches the value at index `x` so just set that to a variable and add it back to your list. You can see this happening if you print `block_list[x]` before and after the `pop()`

```
while 1:
    if block_list[x] == block_list[x-1]:
       y = block_list.pop(x)
       block_list.append(y)
       #Alternatively, but not recommended, is to do .extend([y])
       #That treats y as an element of a list rather than a list itself 
    else:
       break
```

Also the way you have it now you are treating your list as circular. In the first iteration of the first for loop you are comparing index 0 and index -1.
To fix that you will need to use `range()` like so

```
for x in xrange(1,len(block_list)):
    while 1:
        if block_list[x] == block_list[x-1]:
            y = block_list.pop(x)
            block_list.append(y)
        else:
            break

['seq2', 'seq1', 'seq3', 'seq4', 'seq1', 'seq2', 'seq4', 'seq3',
 ...,
 'seq3', 'seq1', 'seq2', 'seq4', 'seq3', 'seq2', 'seq3', 'seq4']
```

Comment: So now I'm not meeting the constraint of having each seq# appear only 24 times, so there should be 96 list items total.

Answer (score 0):

After you shuffle `sequences`, check to see if the first seq of `sequences` matches the last seq of `block_list`.  If they match, just extend with `sequences` in reverse.

```
def rgen():
    sequences = [seq1, seq2, seq3, seq4]
    random.shuffle(sequences)

    for i in range(24):
        random.shuffle(sequences)
        if sequences[:1] != block_list[-1:]:
            block_list.extend(sequences[:])
        else:
            block_list.extend(sequences[::-1])

    return block_list
```

An observation: `rgen()` (yours or mine) can't generate all valid permutations of the sequences.  For example, it can't generate:

```
[seq1 seq2 seq1 .... seq4 seq3 seq4]
```